# Symfony2 - Error: Call to a member function on * a non-object in * --- findByOne array

Tags: arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm stuck and can't figure out why this is not working. This is working fine with I use findOneById(2), yet when I use findOneBy(array(...)) I get the following error "FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getFirstName() on a non-object in... ".

This is from a tutorial that I was following: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seztFo5j7H4 and the code is exactly the same.

Please HELP!!!

**Entity**

```
namespace General\LoginBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Users
 */
class Users
{
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $userName;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $firstName;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $userid;


/**
 * Set userName
 *
 * @param string $userName
 * @return Users
 */
public function setUserName($userName)
{
    $this->userName = $userName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get userName
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getUserName()
{
    return $this->userName;
}

/**
 * Set firstName
 *
 * @param string $firstName
 * @return Users
 */
public function setFirstName($firstName)
{
    $this->firstName = $firstName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get firstName
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getFirstName()
{
    return $this->firstName;
}

/**
 * Set password
 *
 * @param string $password
 * @return Users
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get password
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Get userid
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getUserid()
{
    return $this->userid;
}
}
```

**Controller**

```
 public function indexAction()
{
    $username = 'username';
    $password = 'password';

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $repository = $em->getRepository('GeneralLoginBundle:Users');

    $user = $repository->findOneBy(array(
        'userName' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
    ));

    //        exit(\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($user));

    return $this->render('GeneralLoginBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
        'name' => $user->getFirstName()
    ));
}
```

Comment: I don't think your approach is the best way to handle authentication using Symfony2. Anyway, the error message you got is clear enough to help you figure out what's going wrong, your repository isn't returning any user based on the parameters you're passing.

Comment: This was just practice to understand the process, what do you suggest to better take advantage of authentication using Symfony2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check the $username variable to ensure it's what you're using in the database.

Comment: Turns out I was using something other than 'username', such a simple mistake and pulling my hair out. Thanks.